# replace empty entries in a dictionary with a range of elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list called Customer_Details which consist of dictionaries gotten from my csv file.

```py
[
  {
    'First Name': 'Kieran',
    'Last Name': 'Wilson',
    'Age (Years)': '89',
    'Marital Status': 'married or civil partner',
    'Distance Commuted to Work (miles)': '0',
    'Employer Company': 'N/A',
    'Dependants': '3',
    'Yearly Pension (GBP)': '7257',
    'Sex': 'Male',
    'Retired': 'TRUE',
    'Yearly Salary (GBP)': '72838',
  }
]
```

For "Dependants" some of the rows have empty entries. How do I replace the entries that are empty with a range of values [1 to 5]

```py
Customers_with_dependant_issues = [d for d in Customer_Details if d['Dependants'] == '']
```

I extracted the customers with empty dependant entries.

Comment: You want to cycle through values 1-5? That is, the first missing value is replaced with 1, the second missing value is replaced with 2, and so on?

Comment: Note that in English the standard spelling is "dependent", not "dependant".

Comment: Since you said you want to *replace*  the entries, you probably want to do something like `for ci, c in enumerate(Customer_Details): if not c.get('Dependants'): Customer_Details[ci]['Dependants'] = <some_value_1-5>`, but your q isn't very clear on how to generate exactly what value you'd want to fill with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cycle through replacement values 1 through 5, this can be easily done in several ways.

The most convenient Pythonic technique is to create an *infinite generator* using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). You can then loop through the customer detail entries, directly replacing the missing values.

```py
from itertools import cycle

customer_details = [ ... ]

cycle_1_5 = cycle([1,2,3,4,5])
for customer in customer_details:
    if customer['Dependents'] == '':
        replacement = next(cycle_1_5)
        customer['Dependents'] = replacement
```

`itertools` is included with every Python installation, and it can be very useful for quickly and easily solving problems like this.

Without it, you would have to resort to manually maintaining a counter:

```py
customer_details = [ ... ]

replacement = 1
for customer in customer_details:
    if customer['Dependents'] == '':
        customer['Dependents'] = replacement
        if replacement >= 5:
            replacement = 1
        else:
            replacement += 1
```

In general, *most* programming problems reduce to something along the lines of "loop forward through the data, updating some state at each step". In this case, the "state" to be updated is just the replacement value cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer_Details = [
    {
        'First Name': 'Kieran',
        'Last Name': 'Wilson',
        'Age (Years)': '89',
        'Marital Status': 'married or civil partner',
        'Distance Commuted to Work (miles)': '0',
        'Employer Company': 'N/A',
        'Dependants': '3',
        'Yearly Pension (GBP)': '7257',
        'Sex': 'Male',
        'Retired': 'TRUE',
        'Yearly Salary (GBP)': '72838',
    }
]

# assuming you want to replace with any fixed value (?)
for detail in Customer_Details:
    if detail["Dependants"] == "":
        detail["Dependants"] = 1234
```